# Got the Workflow Field Update working. What is the equivalent DML?

Tags: workflow, dml

In the Formula part of a Field Update Workflow I was able to update a custom field in my Activity Assignment record with the email address of the Owner from the parent Sales Opportunity, using:

```
K__ResourcedActivity__r.K__DeliveryElement__r.K__DeliveryGroup__r.K__SalesOpportunity__r.Owner:User.Email
```

However, when I try to run DML to do the same to all my existing records:

```
K__ActivityAssignment__c aa = [SELECT MY_Sales_Opportunity_Owner__c FROM K__ActivityAssignment__c WHERE MY_Sales_Opportunity_Owner__c ='fred.bloggs@mydomain.com'];
aa.MY_Sales_Opportunity_Owner__c = K__ResourcedActivity__r.K__DeliveryElement__r.K__DeliveryGroup__r.K__SalesOpportunity__r.Owner:User.Email ;
update aa;
```

I get:

Expecting a semi-colon, found ':'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The second line should owner.email instead of owner:user.email.

```
aa.MY_Sales_Opportunity_Owner__c = K__ResourcedActivity__r.K__DeliveryElement__r.K__DeliveryGroup__r.K__SalesOpportunity__r.Owner.email ;
```

Comment: That gives: Variable does not exist: K__ResourcedActivity__r.K__DeliveryElement__r.K__DeliveryGroup__r.K__SalesOpportunity__r.Owner.Email

Comment: is MY_Sales_Opportunity_Owner__c a email field or user lookup?

Comment: My destination custom field is type 'email'. The original 'Owner' field in the parent record is  Lookup(User,Queue)

Comment: Where are you getting this field  K__ResourcedActivity__r.K__DeliveryElement__r.K__DeliveryGroup__r.K__SalesOpportunity__r from ? Are you querying for it?

Comment: Ah, good question. I probably need to query for it in order to set something else equal to it? The only DML I was running was as per my snippet.

Comment: yes, thats correct you need to query to get the value and that was the reason it said variable does not exist

Comment: I'm not sure how to query that? Because I somehow need to lookup the record based on the results of the first query?

Comment: how are the 2 objects related?

Answer (score 0):

In the second line what you mean by `Owner:User` at the end? There is the problem I guess. In addition to that I'm confused whether it's a good idea to have this much of deep relation in a `DML`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure! I'm a bit of a novice, and this was how somebody told me to do it! It seems to get the email address of the Owner of the Sales Opportunity, such that I can write it into my custom field in my child record (Activity Assignment).

Comment: Well it does when used to do a Field Update Workflow anyway.

Comment: I remember now. I built the full path using the INSERT FIELD widget in the Workflow Editor.